# How to refresh a rowrepeater in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have developed a small application in which I have a row repeater where I will display the recently created records.

> Suppose I have some 150 records in a row repeater.
>       Now the problem is I scroll down to see the 100th record in the row repeater
>       and after viewing the 100th record I will go back by clicking on back button.

Now if I again click on the row repeater the page is not displaying from the starting record by default its showing from the 100th record means I again need to scroll up to view the 0th record.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can

- ensure that the RowRepeater (or it's surrounding view) is destroyed on back and recreated on enter (only way known to me to handle your requirement with UI5)
- use `jQuery.scrollTop()` on re-entering the view with your row repeater

  `var oRR = sap.ui.getCore().byId("myRowRepeater"); 
  jQuery(".sapUiRrPage", oRR.getDomRef()).scrollTop();`